# Restarting a python scrip automaticaly when it errors

Tags: python-3.x

question i have made a discord bot and occasionally this errors out and these errors can not be stopped, i was wondering if there is a way to restart the scrip when it errors 
Much Appreciated 
 I am on a windows pc

Comment: why not just something like `while True: try ... except: pass`?

Comment: thing is i dont know what the error can be and the scrip like full on stops so i do need like an external scrip that can read this and restart the bot script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like:

```
try:
    *some code*
except Error1, Error2, Error3:
    pass
```

That should work. I would just add in the errors you get, and when you get a new one, put it in the code.

Hope this helps!