# how to keep Go webservice running

Tags: linux, web-services, service, webserver, go

I am writing some webservices in Go on a linux machine, so the Go executable needs to keep running

which is the best way to do it?

should I setup the Go executable as a service on the linux machine?

many thanks

Comment: What distribution is your sever running?

Comment: the server is a Centos 6.x

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make sure an application keeps running on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298760/how-to-make-sure-an-application-keeps-running-on-linux)

Comment: what about using Upstart? isn't it suitable for webservers?

Comment: Upstart is fine; supervisord, monit, daemontools & Circus all make good alternatives too.  http://tech.cueup.com/blog/2013/03/08/running-daemons/ is a nice feature comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: use the system service manager if you want to keep things super-simple. CentOS currently uses Upstart, and it's well documented and can handle most Go applications without too many problems. There are some good examples of Upstart + Go [here](http://www.olliecastle.com/2013/02/golang-http-server-upstart-script/) and [here](http://wiki.colar.net/golang_revel_init_script)

The long answer: personal preference. [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), [Monit](http://mmonit.com/) and [Circus](http://circus.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.2/) are good options as well, but bring differing levels of complexity. I personally like supervisord, since it has a fairly clear syntax and a good heap of options.

There's also a good run-down here: http://tech.cueup.com/blog/2013/03/08/running-daemons/