# How do I restart a python script on a remote server if it stops?

Tags: python, shell

I have a python script running on a remote server which I start using `nohup python myscript.py &`. I want to restart the script if it stops. I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298774/3534055) but I am not sure if this starts the script. I believe it checks if the script is stopped and starts it if the script is stopped. Also, it requires the `pid` of the script which would be different every time I restart the script.

I also checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/697064/3534055) but I'm not sure if the `nohup` command can be given the `until.. do` loop. Also wouldn't it just restart my script after every 1 second? Can anyone specify how do I write a script to restart the script in case it stops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your own solution, just use a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    python myscript.py
    echo "crashed" >> log
end
```

Make it executable (chmod +x), then run it like `nohup ./thisscript.sh &`.

Or let other software to do it for you (like dm03514 suggested).

Comment: If you just copied that please change the first line, my autocorrect ruined it.

Answer (score 3):

instead of writing your own script you can use the very mature, battle tested, [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to daemonize any script for you.

in addition to automatically restarting there is lots of other functionality it provides, including logging out of the box, it is very widely used to daemonize python scripts

Comment: I'd love to try that but unfortunately I cannot install any thing on the remote server. So I need to write my own script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restart it from within itself you could try:

```
import os, sys

os.execv(__file__, sys.argv) #__file__ for current file or one of your choice
```