# how to keep a python script always running on raspberry pi?

Tags: python, linux

I am making an image processing solution where the Raspberry Pi processes the image using a python script, and sends the result to an Arduino board. I want to keep this system always running, as Raspberry Pi has a Linux kernel, so is there any way to keep the python script on the pi always running?

Comment: Linux should has `cron` to run programs periodically and then they don't have to run all the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make sure an application keeps running on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298760/how-to-make-sure-an-application-keeps-running-on-linux)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you keep terminal running forever, then you can simply use python's While condition

```
while True:
    *do some thing*
```

and keep the program running as long as u need you can also use time module if you want it to sleep for few sec or mins

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if the images will be stored on a folder or how your script will receive the images, but here are 2 options:

1. Setup a cron job to run your script every X seconds/minutes, process all images available and send them to the arduino board
2. Run your script in the background as a service, there are some cool instructions on the following link:
   http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/07/getting-a-python-script-to-run-in-the-background-as-a-service-on-boot/