# Keep open linux app and watch for crash

Tags: linux

Is there way for look at my app, which is opened by terminal? I want to run app when linux loads, and watch them... if crash, then reopened it..

I tried simple sh script, which watch for opened processes every 30 seconds, and if there is no my app, script should start newone.

But ... is this good way to keep app open?

Comment: What kind of app is it? Does it require user interaction?

Comment: no, its Matlab instance ... just run one line command for run

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is to make sure the app doesn't crash, haha. But it does seem like you're basically using a watchdog timer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make sure an application keeps running on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298760/how-to-make-sure-an-application-keeps-running-on-linux)

Comment: Sounds like you should turn it into a service and have e.g. systemd manage it.